# Force-open default browser when clicking link in Gmail iOS app

Tags: ios, browser, webview, gmail

When clicking a link in the Gmail iOS app, an in-app browser opens.

How can I force the default browser to open instead?

I have tried making the link an anchor tag as well as using `window.open` (with target set to `_blank`) but this doesn't help.